# How to unit test a function that requires HTTP request?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a few functions within my Flask app that are based around session management. For example, one updates the value (a datetime.now() value) in a dictionary when a request comes in from a session.

```py
def update_existing_session(active_sessions):
    """[Updates the value of the session in the management dictionary with
    a current timestamp]

    Args:
        active_sessions ([dictionary]): [Dictionary containing session info.
        key = session token, value = last request timestamp]

    Returns:
        active_sessions ([dictionary]): [Updated dictionary of active sessions.
        Key = session token, value = last request timestamp]
    """
    session_name = session.get('public_user')
    logging.info("New request from " + str(session_name))
    active_sessions[session_name] = datetime.now()
    return active_sessions
```

When I try to unit test this, or similar methods which also use sessions, example below, I get the following error:

```py
    def test_generate_new_session(self):
        active_sessions = {}
        active_sessions = session_management.generate_new_session(active_sessions)
        self.assertEqual(len(active_sessions), 1)
 

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

How can I unit test using an active HTTP request, in order to generate the session so that the code runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Flask's [test client](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/):

```py
from your_flask_app import app   # Flask app object


with app.test_client() as client:
    response = client.get('/your-controller-endpoint')
    response = client.post('/your-controller-endpoint', data={'post': 'params'})
```

The Flask documentation generally recommends you use PyTest, which will then let you set up fixtures more easily. Example from the docs:

```py
import os
import tempfile

import pytest

from flaskr import flaskr


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    db_fd, flaskr.app.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
    flaskr.app.config['TESTING'] = True

    with flaskr.app.test_client() as client:
        with flaskr.app.app_context():
            flaskr.init_db()
        yield client

    os.close(db_fd)
    os.unlink(flaskr.app.config['DATABASE'])
```

But the short answer is, just call `test_client()` on your `app` object.